# Python module importing

Tags: python, import, module, init

I'm working on a GUI app.  Let's say that I have a file `main.py` which is in the root directory and I want to import widgets like this:

```
from widgets import FancyWindow, ColorPicker
# ...
```

And my app is structured like so:

```
| main.py
+ widgets/
    | __init__.py
    | fancy_window.py
    | color_picker.py
...
```

IIRC, I would have to import classes from the other modules like so:

```
from widgets.color_picker import ColorPicker
from widgets.fancy_window import FancyWindow
```

So my question is if there is something I can do in `widgets/__init__.py` to make it so that I can do imports in the way I want to?

Comment: In `widgets/__init__.py` import the things you want to be available in the `widget` package's namespace. i.e. `from fancy_window import FancyWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have it there already, just make your `__init__.py` have those two lines:

```
from widgets.color_picker import ColorPicker
from widgets.fancy_window import FancyWindow
```

Anything that you import (and any other symbols you define) in `__init__.py` will then be available.

E.g. if you put:

```
apple = 5
```

in `__init__.py` you could also do: `from widgets import apple`.  No magic :)

Comment: This is the one that worked for me.  But there is still a little odd issue.  If I try to do a `from widgets import *` in `main.py`, I'll get an error from `importlib` telling me `TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string`.  But if I don't do the star and give the actual name of the widget I want, there is no error.

Comment: @Benjamin you'd need to post more code/context for that one - maybe open a different question?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use `__init__.py` to perform setups needed for the package.

```
# __init__.py
from fancy_window import FancyWindow
from color_picker import ColorPicker
```

Then in `main.py` you can perform imports directly.

```
# main.py
from widgets import FancyWindow, ColorPicker
```

A more convenient way to package everything in `__init__.py`

```
# __init__.py
from fancy_window import *
from color_picker import *
```

Answer (score 1):

In `__init__.py` you can import the modules, then export them:

```
from fancy_window import FancyWindow
from color_picker import ColorPicker

__all__ = [FancyWindow, ColorPicker]
```

Now, you can do the following:

```
from widgets import * # Only imports FancyWindow and ColorPicker
from widgets import FancyWindow
from widgets import ColorPicker
import widgets
color_picker = widgets.ColorPicker()
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, by adding the public variables of the other modules to __all__ in __init__.py
see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import